# Using a taglib tag with MarkupBuilder

Tags: grails, taglib, grails3, markupbuilder

I try to call a Grails `Tablib` in combination with the Groovy `MarkupBuilber`

```
MarkupBuilder html = new MarkupBuilder(out)

html.div {
    g.link(controller: "...", action: "...") {
        ...
    }
}
```

As described in the Grails documentation (http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#_rendering_a_response) this is not working because the taglib call return some text that will be ignored by the `MarkupBuilder`

I also found this issue in the grails-gsp project on github (https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/issues/7) with the same problem. In this issue the solution is to use `out <<`.

Is this the correct solution and right way or are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `mkp.yield` or `mkp.yieldUnescaped` for custom text added to builder syntax.

```
MarkupBuilder html = new MarkupBuilder(out)

html.div {
    mkp.yieldUnescaped g.link(controller: "...", action: "...") {
        ...
    }
}
```